# Replacing Wchar_t

Tags: c++, windows

How can I replace string in a `wchar_t` variable?

```
wchar_t text[] = L"Start Notepad.exe";
```

I want to replace `Notepad.exe` with `Word.exe`.

Comment: You can do this by writing the correct code do this, then compiling and executing it.

Comment: Better to use `std::wstring`.

Comment: @Galik Thanks but, Windows expects `wchar_t` for most of its functions and it is really pain to convert from `wstring` to `wchar_t`. That is why I try to use `wchar_t`. Even `wstring.c_str()` does not help because sometimes VS requires it to be not a `constant`. What do you recommend?

Comment: If you want a non-constant `wchar_t*` then you can pass `&text[0]` like: `winfunc(&text[0], text.size());`

Comment: @Galik thanks again. But would there be any issues when using `&text[0]` ? Because I am dealing with international characters for localization.  Not sure if passing first pointer cause any `utf16` character loss? Is not there any standard way for dealing with `wchar_t`?

Comment: There is no difference passing `&text[0]` and passing the address of a `wchar_t` array. In fact the `std::wstring` class is basically just a wrapper around a dynamic `wchar_t*` array.

Comment: You won't even lose any performance because `std::wstring` methods are trivial, inlined and calling them is optimized away by the compiler. Its just as fast as an array (because that's what it is).

Comment: see [Modifying underlying char array of a c++ string object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5729203/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wchar_t is just one character, not the string. In your case you need std::wstring, string consisting of wchar_t. Here is answer on how to [replace one substring with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643512/replace-substring-with-another-substring-c).

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry for the typo. wchar_t is array in my case. Am I still can not replace this way?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use a pointer or index variable and replace the characters one by one and end with the null character.

Here is an example, (note that C++ programmers might hate this code, but is fairly acceptable for C programmers...):

```
wchar_t lpSrcText[] = L"Start Notepad.exe";
wchar_t const * lpReplace = L"Word.exe";

int i = 0;
while(*(lpReplace + i))
{
     lpSrcText[6 + i] = *(lpReplace + i);
     i++;
}
*(lpReplace + i) = L'\0';
```